# Update column to max of column in each update of a single query.

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

I want to update a column whose value is 0 to maximum of that column (In single query).

There are lots of records with 0 value.

I am doing this:

```
UPDATE table SET field = (SELECT MAX(field) + 1) WHERE field = 0;
```

But it updates each record to **same value**.
Can we get max value on each row update?

Comment: I don't get it: why the max should change at every update? Max is max and always the same even after the update..

Comment: can you provide table structure

Comment: @Lorenzo Marcon Suppose there are 3 records with 0. If it update first one to max say 101 remaining two should be 102 and 103. But it puts 101 to each.

Comment: @Snehal like:  id | int_field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want to *increment* the value starting with the next possible value.  Here is one method:

```
update table t cross join
       (select @rn := max(field) from table) var
    set t.field = (@rn := @rn + 1)
    where field = 0;
```

Comment: Its working :) Just a little correction... 
`update table t cross join (select @rn := (select max(field) from table)) var set t.field = (@rn := @rn + 1) where field = 0;`

Comment: @Vitthal . . . It doesn't need the additional subquery.  The query is fixed.